# Selecting only one element in the class onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the code below, I have four elements. When a specific element is clicked, I would like for it to change color. Right now, for some reason, the entire row of elements is changing color, and not the individual element. Here is my code:

```html
<style>
.tag14 span {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    background: brown;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #091747;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: inline-block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
}


}

.tag14 span:focus{
   background:green;
}

</style>

<script>
function myfunction(elmt) 
{
    elmt.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            
}
</script>


<div class="tag14" onclick="myfunction(this);">
    <span class="tag_span">
        Hello
    </span>
    
    <span class="tag_span">
        Hi
    </span>
    
    <span class="tag_span">
        Hello
    </span>
    
    <span class="tag_span">
        Hi
    </span>
    
    <span class="tag_span">
        Hello
    </span>
    
</div>
```

I suspect it has to do with how my class is named and the parameter of the onclick function.

Comment: So, you want the individual span-element to change color when you click the Span-element?

Comment: Yep! When I click on the specific span, I'd like for it to change color from brown to blue.

Comment: You need to put the `onclick` attribute in the spans, not the div.

Comment: BTW, you have an extra `}` in the `style` block.

Comment: `this` is the element with the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use [Element.querySelectorAll(".tag span")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [NodeList.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- Don't use inline `on*` handlers same as you hopefully don't use inline `style` attributes. JavaScript should be in one place only - and that's your `script`.
  Use [Element.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead with [Event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)
- Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to toggle/add/remove a className
- Don't name your functions `myfunction` - cause it means nothing to nobody. name your function exactly as a short describer of the job it does or the value it returns.

```js
const addActiveClass = (evt) => {
  evt.currentTarget.classList.add("is-active")
};

const getUserData = (evt) => {
  const user_id = evt.currentTarget.dataset.userId;
  console.log(`get data of user ID: ${user_id} from DB`);
};

const EL_tag_children = document.querySelectorAll(".tag span");
EL_tag_children.forEach(EL => {
  EL.addEventListener("click", addActiveClass)
  EL.addEventListener("click", getUserData)
});
```

```css
.tag span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: brown;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #091747;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tag span.is-active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <span data-user-id="23">John</span>
  <span data-user-id="566">Amanda</span>
  <span data-user-id="101">Fredrick</span>
  <span data-user-id="42">Paulina</span>
  <span data-user-id="50">Jaqueline</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, the code runs correctly when I do it here is SO, but when I transfer the code to anywhere else, it goes wrong. Is the first box (where the consts are defined) supposed to take the place of what's currently inside myfunction()?

Comment: @youewew run the above snippet. Right click and Inspect element. Inspect the Iframe's <body> to see how it all ended up constructed... Tl;Dr - always place your (not deferred) `<script>` tags right before your closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @youewew make sure the DOM is loaded before calling your script

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out by inspecting the element. If I want other things to happen when a specific span is clicked, I assume I put those other things in `changeColor` after `evt.currentTarget.classList.add("is-active");` ?

Comment: @youewew please explain, what *other things* you want to happen? Yes, name your `addActiveClass` differently, and inside a block `{}` place all your desired transformations! `const addActiveClass = (evt) => { /* whatever your want to happen on SPAN click */ console.log(evt); };`

Comment: @youewew Perhaps the best would be to ***edit*** and improve your question by adding the missing details.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Definitely! So my real data will be populated with names of people from a database, not just Hi and Hello. When one of these names is clicked, it will change the color of the element (to show that the person has been selected) and also pull and display all that person's information from the database.

Comment: @youewew edited my answer - hope it makes sense how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tag_span")).forEach(function(element) {
  element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue"; 
  });
});
```

```css
.tag14 span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: brown;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #091747;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag14">
  <span class="tag_span">
    Hello
  </span>
  <span class="tag_span">
    Hi
  </span>
  <span class="tag_span">
    Hello
  </span>
  <span class="tag_span">
    Hi
  </span>
  <span class="tag_span">
    Hello
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Array.from? NodeList has a nifty native forEach Method. Also, Never, ever use `e.target` unless you really, really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Youre pretty close. If you would use `onclick=myfunction(event)` with `event.target` it'd pretty much do what you want.

```js
function myfunction(event) {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```css
.tag14 span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: brown;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #091747;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag14" onclick="myfunction(event);">
  <span class="tag_span">
        Hello
    </span>

  <span class="tag_span">
        Hi
    </span>

  <span class="tag_span">
        Hello
    </span>

  <span class="tag_span">
        Hi
    </span>

  <span class="tag_span">
        Hello
    </span>

</div>
```

A better approach would be to not use `onevent` handlers and just use pure JavaScript, as the accepted answer mentioned. However there is a distinct difference between your code and the accepted answers and that is the code wont function if you dynamically add new tags. That is because the events are bound specifically to an element, were in your code the event is bound on the parent which will allow events triggered from its children to be handled by the parent. This is known as event delegation and has some pretty nice perks. The biggest one, is there is just no book keeping required on the children elements. They can enter and leave without having to bind and unbind handlers. This obviously doesn't matter if you don't plan on adding elements dynamically but it's still something to watch out for.

Below is a pure JavaScript implementation of your code with dynamic elements.

```js
const $tag = document.querySelector(".tag");

$tag.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let target = e.target;

  if (!target.matches(".tag > span")) {
    const path = e.composedPath()
      .slice(0, -2)
      .reverse();

    target = path.find((e) => e.matches('.tag > span'));
  }

  if (target != null) {
    target.classList.toggle("is-active");
  }
});

const $form = document.querySelector("form");

$form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.target["newTag"].value !== "") {
    const $entry = document.createElement("span");
    $entry.innerText = e.target["newTag"].value;

    $tag.append($entry);
  }

  e.target["newTag"].value = "";
});
```

```css
.tag span {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: brown;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #091747;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 4px 8px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.tag span.is-active {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hello</span>
  <span>Hi</span>
  <span>Hello <strong>there</strong></span>
</div>

<form>
  <input name="newTag" />
  <button>add</button>
</form>
```

We listen for all clicks on the parent `.tag` element and we decide what we want to do. We then will match interesting elements using two conditions. An element is interesting if its a `.tag > span`. But since anything can trigger a click inside `.tag`, we need also need to figure out if a clicked element is inside a `.tag > span`. That is because `event.target` will only show us what triggered the event and on more complex element that's not always a `.tag > span` but could be a child. We used `event.composedPath` to give us the event propagation path, we `slice` of the last 2 to because the event will end up in window and document which aren't useful to us. The `reverse` operation just makes it more convenient to find the first parent matching our selector without having to iterate over the path in in reverse. An example would be the `hello there` tag. Finally if we find a match, just toggle the class name.

Comment: Did you not read my post? Because I literally explain all of this and provide a solution in my second example. `closest('span')` has such a low level of specificity that'd it match any span from target to currenttarget, you'd want to match direct span descendants of `.tag` which is what I'm doing.